# SQL2094W The rebalance of table space fails with Reason code: "3"

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

`Alter tablespace ts1 rebalance` command failed with insufficient disk space.

During rebalance its occupy 200GB space and after rebalance fail, it does not release the space.

How this 200GB space to be released? DB2 version is 10.5.0.5

Comment: Rebalancing will not release unused space. `REORG TABLE` might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter tablespace ts1 reduce, release the free space.